# How to create REST API endpoint dynamically in ASP.NET WebAPI 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I need to create a web API app, based on ASP.NET WebAPI2 (not ASP.NET Core), that has the ability to create endpoints at runtime.

For example, I'll need the power users to instruct the app to create a new endpoint at `api/products` which did not exist before, and route that endpoint to a dynamically loaded class.

How can that be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Security? I think it is not a good solution. Try to apply security policies to current user.
If it is not for Security reason, please tell us why is that?

Comment: This seems like an x/y problem. However you could just use a a static endpoint and route and reflect the class